# How do i implement roll over functions to multiple buttons that have been already created?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the buttons for a website and add rollover colours onto them. I have tried so many solutions and none seem to be working. I'm very inexperienced with coding.

I have tried to use many other sources, but they all start from scratch and I don't really understand how I can implement them into my program.

This is the piece of code in my `style.css` file:

```css
li{
    display:inline;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left:80.5px;
    padding-right:80.5px;
    border:inset;
    background-color:White;
    color:aquamarine
}
```

And these are the buttons on each page:

```html
<u1>
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="General Information.html">General Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="Find Us.html">Find us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</u1>
```

I expect the colour of the buttons shown above to change colour when I hold my mouse over them.

Comment: This is the code used on each page for the buttons:
    <u1>
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="General Information.html">General Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="Find Us.html">Find us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </u1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    li {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        border: inset;
        background-color: White;
        color: aquamarine
    }

    .list a {
        padding: 0 80.5px;
    }

    .list a:hover {
        color: springgreen;
        background-color: brown;
    }

<u1 class="list">
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="General Information.html">General Information</a</li>
    <li><a href="Find Us.html">Find us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</u1>
```

Comment: Please add a brief but understandable explanation of your code so that anyone can pick up what's the purpose of this snippet and how it works.